# Custom validator breaks password change form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

We are attempting to add a custom validator to our password reset page in Django 1.11.18. Below is a simplified version of what we have implemented. However, there seems to be an unusual side effect in the form that renders the password reset page. I am expecting 3 fields, `old_password`, `new_password1` and `new_password2`, but `new_password1` is not rendered on the page. We are using almost all of the default Django password change functionality, as can be seen in **views.py** below. If the validator is removed from settings, the form works as expected.

Why is the validator breaking the form?

**myvalidator.py**

```py
import re

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class MyValidator(object):
    message = _("Password is not complex enough (%s)")
    code = "complexity"

    def __init__(self, complexities=None):
        self.complexities = complexities

    def validate(self, password, user=None):
        errors = []
        if password == '12345678':
           errors.append(_("Password must be 12345678"))

        if errors:
            raise ValidationError(self.message % (_(u'must contain ') + u', '.join(errors),),
                                  code=self.code)

    def get_help_text(self):
        return _(
            "Your password must contain 12345678"
        )
```

**views.py**

```py
class PasswordChangeView(views.PasswordChangeView):
    template_name = 'accounts/password_change.html'
```

**settings.py**

```py
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'min_length': 8,
        }
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'the.path.to.myvalidator.MyValidator',
    },
]
```

**password_change.html**

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="row mb20">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label class="pb5" for="{{ form.old_password.id_for_label }}"
        >{{ form.old_password.label }}</label
      >
      {{ form.old_password }} {{ form.old_password.errors }}
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row mb20">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label class="pb5" for="{{ form.new_password1.id_for_label }}"
        >{{ form.new_password1.label }}</label
      >
      {{ form.new_password1 }} {{ form.new_password1.errors }}
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row mb20">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label class="pb5" for="{{ form.new_password2.id_for_label }}"
        >{{ form.new_password2.label }}</label
      >
      {{ form.new_password2 }} {{ form.new_password2.errors }}
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="clearfix mt20 text-right">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sf-lightblue ml10">
      <span class="fa fa-floppy-o"></span> Change my password
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Share the template. Nothing else you've posted should affect rendering of the field.

Comment: @4140tm I added it, but like I said, the template works fine if I remove the custom validator from `settings.py`

Comment: Sorry, overlooked that. I tested what you've shared and couldn't reproduce the described issue. I faced another one, though - the string interpolation in `ValidationError` throws another exception

Comment: @4140tm Thanks for your efforts, we found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

We realised it was an indentation error of the `get_help_text` function. The error wasn't getting properly handled in Django for some reason. It was very difficult to track down.